# Is this normalized correctly?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, diagram, database-normalization, erd

I need to normalize this database. This is for an application that will be allowing users to sign up for gaming tournaments that will be hosted at actual locations. When you search for a tournament the user can either register for the tournament, sponsor the event, or view the tournament. There will be multiple tournaments such as Fortnite, Apex, and what have you. The games will be on platforms like PS4 , PC, and Xbox one. Multiple players can be in a tournament, and they can be signed up for multiple tournaments at a time, same for viewers and sponsors. Each result should be stored such as wins and losses, and be put into the leaderboards. Please help me normalize this ERD diagram.

[image]

Comment: Poor title. Summarize your specific issue, to differentiate from all the other normalization questions.

Comment: Please show & justify the steps of your work following a published academic textbook & ask a specific question where stuck. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual & do your (home)work for you & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. PS What do you think "normalize" means?

Answer (score 0):

To normalize a database you have to make sure of the following rules:

1) Values in each column of a table are atomic.

I'm not sure what do you intend to keep in the wins and losses columns of your tables. But they have to be atomic. The number of wins is ok, but what are the wins is not.

2) No duplicities

I'm not seeing any obvious duplicity so I think this part is Ok.

3) No transitive dependency

In the Tournament Table there are both Teams and Gamer FK. If the gamer can only be in a Tournament if he is on a team, so you have a transitive dependency and should remove the GamerTag of the table. The same goes for the LeaderBoard and Results Table

There are other corrections, like in the Game tables theres an 'attribute name' column. In Team table the TournamentID is not set as FK, and GamerTag is not a FK because is not a PK in the gamer Table. User table has an 'attribute name' also. Among others.

Besides that, I'm not sure that this model will actually do what you want it to do. In general the names of your columns are not mnemonic so I cant be 100% sure of what they are. Like the what is the Leader Fk in Results table.

For a first model it's a good start. I recommend, before you continue to normalize it, revise it with care, write what are the purpose to each column.

Normalization is a nice thing to do with your tables but is not always the best way to store them. So I would also stop to think if it's really necessary to do it.

Comment: This is too vague to be of any use. Eg it is transitive FDs of non-prime attributes on CKs that violate 3NF.